# An array is ending with a  character(")") inside array element value, not with actual array end

Tags: php, arrays

An array which is populated it's value from database. when I `print_r` the array . It shows like below...

```
Array 
(

  [term] => These are following selection a) new  b) old

)
```

Here the array is ending with character `)` inside the term element " ..selection a`)` new ..", while it's only a character in the array. So How I would avoid the ending of array with charcters present inside the array ?

Comment: How exactly is the array "terminating there"? Could you provide some code that demonstrates the problem you're running into?

Comment: Could you show the code you use to declare this with?

Comment: Post the code that creates the array.

Comment: can you post the code that created this array?

Comment: That example is invalid syntax. Please quote your *actual* code. (If that is your code, then that's your answer: The syntax is invalid, revisit the [php arrays page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).)

Comment: Does *anyone* know how to ask a question on SO?

Comment: @all: It's array populated from database. It contain the character `)` inside the array's value

Comment: @Jusnit: So what is the problem?

Comment: @Jusnit: Use `var_dump` instead of `print_r`, it will show you more obviously that there isn't any issue at all. `print_r` is just informative (human readable, less technical correct), it is not the actual array, see http://php.net/print_r

Answer (score 2):

What you're viewing is the output of an array with print_r.

Defining an array in PHP is a little different:

```
$variable = array('inside First a) new, b) old');
print_r($variable);
var_dump($variable); // similar to print_r
```

There is also another way of doing that:

```
$variable = array();
$variable[0] = 'inside First a) new, b) old';
```

So you need to quote your value to get a string.

Comment: @Lumbio: It's an array populated from database. So how would I create an array like here ?

Comment: @Jusnit: how is you database-request?
Usually you do something like [this](http://pastebin.com/MM4qwMhg)
(this is just an example - there are better ways to do that)

Answer (score 0):

The array value in your declaration should be a string:

```
$myArray = array(
    0 => 'inside First a) new , b) old';
);
```

Comment: I am not declaring an array here, but the array is created as an output for a query. The character `)` is saved in database  field.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you need to quote string values:

```
$array =  array(
  0 => 'inside First a) new , b) old'
);
```

See the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php). To be honest this is pretty basic stuff. If you don't know this, I'd suggest going away and getting a basic introduction to PHP book and reading through it...

Comment: Thanks for your response and advice. I am not declaring an array here, but the array is created as a output for a query. The character `)` is saved in database  field.